# Consume SOAP 1.1 WebServices with Bonita Open Solution Secure Web Service Connector

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, business-process-management

I don´t succeed in consuming a SOAP 1.1 Web Service with the "WebService SOAP 1.2" Connector in Bonita Open Solution Studio 6.1 Community. Maybe this could be caused by the Bindung-Id (just an idea, I cannot prove it). Connector forces me to use binding : "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/". As far as I know this binding is related to SOAP 1.2. But what about SOAP 1.1? When I use the SOAP 1.1 binding: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" the connector says that I use the wrong binding ID. As I said, I don´t know if this is the cause.

Even though all parameters are correct (endpoint address, SOAP-Action, envelope etc...), I cannot invoke the SOAP 1.1 service because of the error: **Exception trying to call remote webservice**

I think this is a very common use case because there are many business information systems still using SOAP 1.1.

Comment: did you tried with soap 1.2 before ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the Bonita connector with a SOAP 1.2 web service and it worked fine. In one certain process, I need to invoke a web service from a IBM ECM System. This system only offers the services via SOAP 1.1